# Confusion of substitution of KdV equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am studying the solitary wave of KdV equation. In my study I reached the equation, where $u(x,t) = v(x-ct) = v(\xi)$,

$$v''(\xi) -cv(\xi)-3 v^2(\xi)=0.$$

The author said: by rescaling $\xi = \sqrt{c} \zeta$ and $v=c \overline{v}$ we get the system

$$\overline{v}''=\overline{v}+ 3 \overline{v}^2$$

where $\overline{v} = \overline{v}(\zeta)$, I guess.

I have done more complicated substitutions but I think there is a typo here in the book because according to his asumptions the system is not going to be independent of c. Could you please help me if I wrong

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why the author's assumptions should mean there's a typo?

Comment: Using the rescalings in the book, you get (using the chain rule on the derivatives) \begin{align} v &\to c \bar{v} \\ v' &\to c (\sqrt{c}) \bar{v}' \\ v'' &\to c (\sqrt{c})^{2} \bar{v}'' \end{align} and substituting this into the ODE we get $$0 = c (\sqrt{c})^{2} \bar{v}'' - c (c \bar{v}) - 3 (c \bar{v})^{2} = c (\bar{v}'' - \bar{v} - 3 \bar{v}^{2})$$ so there is no typo.